# sed refuses to replace pattern -> file (encoding) error?

Tags: character-encoding, sed

I'm having a strange problem for which I don't see any explanation. I have a file with the following content:

```
<me@mycomp:~> head -n 2 myfile
f800671 1 V80068 0.000 2.262 DUMMY heeft één van hen niet gezegd
f800671 1 V80068 2.262 4.090 DUMMY la*v Belgique*v sera*v latine*v
```

I want to remove all the *v (foreign word) markers as follows:

```
<me@mycomp:~> head -n 2 myfile | sed 's/*v//'
f800671 1 V80068 0.000 2.262 DUMMY heeft één van hen niet gezegd
f800671 1 V80068 2.262 4.090 DUMMY la*v Belgique*v sera*v latine*v
```

No luck there. The sed command seems to be correct. It's a basic command, so not much risk there, but I checked it anyway:

```
echo "Belgique*v" | sed 's/*v//'
Belgique
```

I assume that there is something wrong with the file, but I honestly can't imagine what. I checked the encoding and it's plain ISO-8859 text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `*` and use the `g` flag for global replace:

```
sed 's/\*v//g'
```

**Edit:**

`*` means 'zero or more of the preceeding'. Do disable this special meaning, you must escape it as `\*`.

The `g` flag replaces *all* occurences. If you don't set this flag, only the *first* occurence will be replaced.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot or I should have at least gotten a coffee first. I completely forgot about the g flag.

Comment: `*` is not special as first character, at least in my `sed` version. No need to escape it, but I agree it's a good habit.